# Как подключить стили?

Tags: css

Даже не знаю как правильно спросить. 
Допустим есть большой CSS файл где много одинаковых стилей (например `color:#000`). Как мне прописать этот стиль только один раз и чтобы он передавался во все строки где есть например `color: какое-то слово` или что-то в этом духе. Видел на CodePen, что так делают, но хоть убей не помню и даже не знаю по каким словам искать

Comment: Не стоит так делать. Это не кроссбраузерно и многие браузера не поддерживают переменные CSS.

Comment: http://frontender.info/css-variables-why-should-you-care/ или https://habrahabr.ru/post/141920/

Comment: Можно использовать SASS https://sass-scss.ru/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается такое через переменные CSS:

```css
html {
  --color: red;
}

span {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<span>Цвет</span>
```

Но не советую их использовать, так как способ не кроссбраузерный и в старых версиях браузеров вообще не поддерживаются.

Comment: а чё такое var ?

Comment: Вместо этого `--color` можно, что угодно написать?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, `var` - это переменная

Comment: @steep, перед текстом ставить `--` нужно

Comment: @Yuri да я понял что переменная , но разве в css они применяются ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я же написал: "Но не советую их использовать, так как способ не кроссбраузерный и в старых версиях браузеров вообще не поддерживаются."

Answer (score 1):

Используйте предпроцессоры, такие как [sass/scss](https://sass-scss.ru)
или [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com). Они поддерживают переменные, функции, вложенность и еще много других плюшек)